# What's the difference between Vanishing Twin Syndrome & Fetus in Fetu?

Tags: fetus

**What is the medical/clinical difference between Vanishing Twin Syndrome and Fetus in Fetu??**

**General Differences:**

- I know that in both cases, there is a **set of twins, but then there
  is just one fetus in the end**. *So is the difference on how that
  comes to be?? Or on how the case manifests itself?*

**Vanishing Twin Syndrome**

- From what I understand about **"Vanishing Twin Syndrome"** is that
  one of the twins is **absorbed by another** (sometimes due to it
  being a blighted ovum)?
- *But are there any times in which the alpha    fetus absorbed a fetus that would have survived?*

**Fetus in Fetu**

- And with Fetus in Fetu -- A **fetus (or teratoma) that dies** is not
  absorbed by the other growing twin, but **exists as a separate entity**
  **inside the fetus** that will survive?
- And with Fetus in Fetu --- is    it really thought to be a teratoma and not just a non-viable fetus?

Is this correct?